# Plogjuttler visualizes ROS topics from ssh remotely connected machine

Tags: ssh, ip, ros

Background:
Machine A running ROS1 that has a SSH server (IP: 11.11.11.11).
Machine B has plotjuggler, which is my remote station (IP: 22.22.22.22).

What works:
On machine B, I can ssh to machine A using command line.

What NOT works:
Using Plotjuggler running B to visualize ROS topics on A doesn't work. I tried configuration in below figure, it doesn't work.

[image]

But I'd like to visualize ros topics using plogjuggler. How can I configure the system to achieve this?

Edit: maybe a related question, how can I see topics on machine B using

```
rostopic echo /status_report
```

Comment: A little more information is needed. Can you see the ros topic data on machine B at all via `rostopic echo`? Can machine B and machine A communicate at all?

Comment: Thank you. No. I can't see ROS topics on machine B via `rostopic echo`. I don't know how to see ROS topics on machine B. I also edited the original question to include this detail.